# Xamarin android vibrate do not work when screen is locked

Tags: android, xamarin, locking, screen, vibration

I have been trying to get my android phone to vibrate when the screen locked, the code below is to receive sms messages and vibrate. I have seen multiple examples to vibrate while the screen is locked but I could never get it to work. I am new to mobile app development. below the code works well for a Samsung Galaxy note 9 when the screen lock is off. I have the permissions set in the manifest to vibrate and to receive SMS. but it just fails when screen is lock is on. Could somebody look at my code and get it vibrate while the screen is locked.

I would greatly Appreciate it. Please Post full example that I could use once again I am new to mobile development.

```
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver", Exported = true)]
[IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" }, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.HighPriority)]
public class MySMSReciver : BroadcastReceiver
{ 
    public static readonly String INTENT_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    protected string message, address = "";
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        InvokeAbortBroadcast();
        try
        {
            if (intent.Action != INTENT_ACTION) return;

            var bundle = intent.Extras;

            if (bundle == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            var pdus = bundle.Get("pdus").ToArray<Java.Lang.Object>();
            var msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.Length];
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            String sender = null;
            String messageBody = null;             
            for (int i = 0; i < msgs.Length; i++)
            {

                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.CreateFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);

                messageBody = msgs[i].MessageBody;

                if (sender == null)
                {
                    sender = msgs[i].OriginatingAddress;

                }

                sb.Append(string.Format("SMS From: {0}{1}Body: {2}{1}", msgs[i].OriginatingAddress, System.Environment.NewLine, messageBody));

            }

            if (sender != null)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, "your SMS Message:" +  sb.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //works well but fails when screen is locked.
                var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
            }
         else
           {
             ClearAbortBroadcast();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Toast.MakeText(context, "Error :" +ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
        }

     }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use foreground service,refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services

And here is a sample of it:https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples/ForegroundServiceDemo